# vue RouterLink is not working properly in ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vue-component

when Im using router-link in ionic vue, the first navigation is ok, but when I try to navigate for the second time or even when I press browser back button I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "classList", enteringEl is undefined

these are my components that I tried testing:

Products:

```html
<template>
  <master-layout pageTitle="Login Form">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Product Page</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Test<br/>
      <RouterLink to="/Warehouses">Warehouses</RouterLink>
    </ion-card-content>
  </master-layout>
</template>

<script>
import {
  IonCardHeader, IonCardTitle, IonCardContent,RouterLink
} from "@ionic/vue";

export default {
  components: {
    IonCardHeader, IonCardTitle, IonCardContent,RouterLink
  }
};
</script>
```

warehouses:

```html
<template>
  <master-layout pageTitle="Login Form">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title>Warehouse Page</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      Warehouse<br/>
      <RouterLink to="/Products">Products</RouterLink>
    </ion-card-content>
  </master-layout>
</template>

<script>
import {
  IonCardHeader, IonCardTitle, IonCardContent,RouterLink
} from "@ionic/vue";

export default {
  components: {
    IonCardHeader, IonCardTitle, IonCardContent,RouterLink
  }
};
</script>
```

now when I start navigating from products, when I click on warehouses, its ok and I navigate to warehouses, but when I click back button or products link, I get the error I said above.

any suggestion in what is causing this problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: I have tried router-link instead of RouterLink and the problem still exists

Comment: did you find a solution to this @Godfather?

Comment: yes I did, check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for those who have the same problem, this is the solution:
wrap your template in `<ion-page></ion-page>` so it would be:

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    ...
  </ion-page>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks! This one that took me a while. As an addition for others with the same problem: make sure to include the IonPage component in your imports.